# Kill runhaskell process on Windows

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've got a haskell program I'm executing with runhaskell on Windows. The program sits in an infinite loop listening on a network socket. I can't kill the program with ctrl-c, ctrl-d or ctrl-z and my keyboard doesn't have a break key.

Is there anything else I can try to kill the process without having to resort to task manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
taskkill /IM runhaskell
```

I'm guessing at the process name here; if not `runhaskell` replace it with what it really is.

Comment: On my system (haskell-platform-2010.2.0.0) it is indeed `runhaskell.exe`